# Unable to add two paragraphs in open xml word document

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, openxml

I am new to Open XML. This is what I have been able to achieve so far:

1. Create a Word Document
2. Add a Paragraph with some text
3. Align text by changing justification property of paragraph
4. Change font size & bold (on/off)

I am trying to add two paragraphs with different font size and justifications.
This is my code:

```
Dim FontHeading As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FontSize
FontHeading.Val = New StringValue("28")

Dim FontSubHeading As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FontSize
FontSubHeading.Val = New StringValue("24")

Dim wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(Server.MapPath("/test.docx"), WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()
mainPart.Document = New Document()

Dim dbody As New Body

dbody.AppendChild(AddParagraph("PREM CORPORATE", FontHeading, FontBold, CenterJustification))
dbody.AppendChild(AddParagraph("Company Incorporation Documents", FontSubHeading, FontBold, CenterJustification))

mainPart.Document.AppendChild(dbody)
mainPart.Document.Save()
wordDocument.Close()
```

Function to add paragraph:

```
Private Function AddParagraph(ByVal txt As String, ByVal fsize As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FontSize, ByVal fbold As Bold, ByVal pjustification As Justification) As Paragraph

   Dim runProp As New RunProperties
   runProp.Append(fsize)
   runProp.Append(fbold)

   Dim run As New Run
   run.Append(runProp)
   run.Append(New Text(txt))

   Dim pp As New ParagraphProperties
   pp.Justification = pjustification

   Dim p As Paragraph = New Paragraph
   p.Append(pp)
   p.Append(run)

   Return p

End Function
```

The above results in an empty document.
If I remove the second dbody.AppendChild line, then it successfully adds  the first paragraph.

Please help what do I need to change/add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add the *same instance* of the `Bold` and `Justification` objects to different `Paragraphs`. This isn't allowed and should result in the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException - Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.

To get round this you should create a new `Bold` and a new `Justification` each time you need one.

In your `AddParagraph` method you could just take a `Boolean` to denote whether or not the text should be bold and a `JustificationValues` to denote the justification to use then create new instances of each as required:

```
Private Function AddParagraph(txt As String, fsize As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FontSize, bold As Boolean, pjustification As JustificationValues) As Paragraph
    Dim runProp As New RunProperties()
    runProp.Append(fsize)
    If bold Then
        runProp.Append(New Bold())
    End If

    Dim run As New Run()
    run.Append(runProp)
    run.Append(New Text(txt))

    Dim pp As New ParagraphProperties()
    pp.Justification = New Justification() With { _
        Key .Val = pjustification _
    }

    Dim p As New Paragraph()
    p.Append(pp)
    p.Append(run)

    Return p

End Function
```

Your calls to add the `Paragraphs` would then be something like this:

```
dbody.AppendChild(AddParagraph("PREM CORPORATE", FontHeading, True, JustificationValues.Center))
dbody.AppendChild(AddParagraph("Company Incorporation Documents", FontSubHeading, True, JustificationValues.Center))
```